# Equivalent of struct->ptr = (char*) data in rust

Tags: rust

There's the following line in C:

`my_struct->ptr = (char*) data`

where as you can see, `my_struct` has a `ptr` member of type `char*`

I have this on Rust:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    ptr: *mut libc::c_char
}
```

then I fill it like this:

```rust
unsafe{*my_struct}.ptr = Box::into_raw(my_data) as *mut libc::c_char;
unsafe{((*my_struct).ptr as *mut MyData).as_mut()}.unwrap();
```

but I'm getting either an unwrap panic on the line above. See that I acessed it immeidately after setting it, so no lifetime, out of scope problems for this data.

Here's the actual `MyStruct`:

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/include/mysql/udf_registration_types.h#L69

**I think the problem is resumed here:**

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=293ca891bedb9528ae840bcdf737777c

or in other words:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct MyStruct {
    ptr: *mut libc::c_char
}

struct MyData{}

fn main() {
    let my_struct = &mut MyStruct{
        ptr: std::ptr::null_mut()
    } as *mut MyStruct;
    let my_data = Box::new(MyData{});
    unsafe{*my_struct}.ptr = Box::into_raw(my_data) as *mut libc::c_char;
    unsafe{((*my_struct).ptr as *mut MyData).as_mut()}.unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `unsafe{*my_struct}.ptr`, you're **copying** `*my_struct`, then overwriting `.ptr` of that **copy**, which is why you're observing no change. Instead, write to `(*my_struct).ptr`:

```rust
unsafe {
    (*my_struct).ptr = Box::into_raw(my_data) as *mut libc::c_char;
}
```

Comment: why does `unsafe{*my_struct}` copies the struct but not `(*my_struct)`?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs `{}` is used to make a scope so it'll be interpreted as a value. It's essentially like writing `let x = unsafe{*my_struct}; x.ptr = ...` which is obviously a copy. `()` is special and used for grouping so it won't be treated as a value.

Comment: And *that* is imo why it was a good idea of Rust to make structs uncopyable by default. I'd also advise you to remove the `Copy` from the `derive` list, and use explicit `.clone()` instead when needed. *Especially* if you have a raw pointer in it that you need to track the lifetime of; I'd almost go so far as to say you should remove the `Clone` as well and implement `Clone` manually if required, to include a refcounter or similar.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Just to demonstrate: Without `Copy`, this entire problem [would have been a compile time error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6e5f84fb23131e16e81e4acbb4dfdb56) instead.

Comment: Probably better would be to dereference-and-borrow to convert to a Rust reference? `unsafe { &*my_struct }.ptr` -- This limits the unsafe scope.

Comment: @cdhowie Disagree ... Undefined behaviour should stay inside of unsafe blocks. Passing a reference to a type of unmanaged lifetime out of an unsafe block is imo a violation of that principle. References give the impression of having managed lifetimes, which `my_struct` doesn't have in this case.

Comment: @cdhowie I think it'd have to be `&mut` but that's also an option, not sure if it's a good one though

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant `&mut`. Personally I'd prefer having the unsafe scope be smaller as a bug would indicate that _that_ is where the problem lies -- in the assumption of the reference's lifetime. But that's my preference.

Comment: The discussion whether `unsafe` block should be as minimal as possible or scope the entire UB land is long and old; there are claims to both sides. I support the option they should be as focused as possible, though not _that_ small. Just my two cents: two disadvantages of "big" unsafe blocks is that they're (a) sometimes unable to cover the whole soundness proof nevertheless because it crosses function bondaries; and (b) may hide unintentional `unsafe` code. Although I would not go so far as adding a reborrow and just wrap the entire assignment in an `unsafe` block.